# Azure RedisCache Backplane Logging/Signalr logging

Tags: signalr, azure-redis-cache, signalr-backplane, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a Single Page Azure Web App that uses Signalr(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-alpha1-final) to broadcast events(login, logout, department creation etc) to connected clients.

I also scale my application to several instances at peak times and i use Redis Cache Backplane (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Redis" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-final) to distribute event broadcast messages to all connected clients

i use angular front end (@aspnet/signalr-client": "^1.0.0-alpha2-final)

on azure, i enabled diagnostic log to log information and error messages.

the above works fine but when i scale up the application, it is difficult to trace information or error messages as i have to look through up to 10 instance application logs to find information or error;

**my question: How do i ensure redis cache logs error messages or information on all available instances rather than on instances where client is connected; how do i know if a client has missed out on event broadcast message? how do i ensure signalr sever/hub logs all messages on all application log instances?**

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this might be to use the redis-cli, run the MONITOR command and then pipe that to a file (or somewhere that can store the logs).